# ¿Porque un echo para una sola etiqueta HTML?

Tags: php, html

He notado en muchisimos tutoriales de php  ubican las etiquetas html separadas. Por Ejemplo :

```
echo "<h1>Datos extraidos:</h1>";
echo "<b>dato</b>";
echo "<b>Otro dato";
```

¿Porque no las ubican de este modo?:

```
echo "<h1>Datos extraidos:</h1> <br> <b>Dato</b> <br> <b>Otro Dato</b>"
```

Comment: En resumen: legibilidad y mantenimiento de código. No obstante es criterio de cada uno.

Comment: Pues para que sea mas facil y claro para los mas novatos.

Comment: Ojo porque tu segunda opción no hace lo mismo que la primera. La etiqueta <br/> crea un salto de línea en la salida de HTML. Es decir, después de cada linea, tendrás un salto a una nueva.

El equivalente realmente sería este:

`echo "<h1>Datos extraidos:</h1> \n <b>Dato</b> \n <b>Otro Dato</b>"`

Answer (score 1):

Eso depende del programador.

Veamos algunos ejemplos y prácticas usuales.

### PHP + HTML por bloques

En archivos PHP que combinan con contenido HTM, se pueden abrir segmentos de sólo HTML, sobre todo cuando hay que colocar mucho contenido sólo HTML.

Para ello se cierra la etiqueta PHP y se escribe el código HTML directamente:

```
<?php

código php ...

?>

<h1>Esto es todo HTML</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    ... más contenido HTML
    <p>Ya abriremos de nuevo PHP</p>

<?php
... sigue código PHP
```

En tu ejemplo se podría proceder así, colocando todo el contenido HTML en un bloque de sólo HTML:

```
<h1>Datos extraídos</h1>
    <p><b>Dato:</b> texto de dato.</p>
    <p><b>Otro dato:</b> texto de otro dato</p>
```

### HTML+PHP con bucles

#### Una posibilidad es esta:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $user->name ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

#### Otra posibilidad es concatenando una variable:

Aquí nos mantendríamos siempre en PHP, sin combinar. Proporciona un código más legible:

```
<?php
$html="<ul>";

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $html.="<li>".$user->name."</li>";
}
 $html.="</ul>";

echo $html;
?>
```

### Conclusión

Estas son sólo algunas posiblidades. Como se ha dicho, se trata de legilibidad de código.

Es más si quieres puedes hacer código como este:

```
<?php echo "L" ?> 
o 
<?php echo "r" ?> 
e 
<?php echo "m" ?>
```

Espero que no te decidas por esta última posibilidad :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagina que tienes el código:

```
echo "<li>One</li><li>Two</li>><li>Three</li><li>Four</li>";
```

En general uno más complejo toma tiempo leerlo y a veces cuesta trabajo, ahora imagina si:

```
echo "<li>One</li>";
echo "<li>Two</li>";
echo "<li>Three</li>";
echo "<li>Four</li>";
```

Está más legible, lo que permite encontrar errores más fácilmente y ayudar a otros programadores a entenderlo mejor, por ejemplo en un código abierto donde varias personas lo tienen que leer.

Además si mencionas que lo haz visto en tutoriales, es para que quien lo vea lo entienda mejor.