# Agregar un ciclo for dentro de un echo con php

Tags: php, html, ciclos

Saludos, estoy haciendo un ciclo for en un echo y me da un error de sintaxis.
Este es el codigo

`<?php $resultado = '<html><h2>Productos:</h2><p>'.for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST["productos"]); $i++){
echo '<b>'.$_POST["productos"][$i].'</b>';
}.'</p></html>'; ?>`
cabe mencionar que es un array los productos que estoy recibiendo

Comment: y cual es el error exacto que te da?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) on line 96

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tú puedes combinar código de PHP/HTML, pero para hacerlo, debes abrir y cerrar las etiquetas de código PHP cada vez que vayas a usar HTML y viceversa. En cuanto al `for`, no se trata de una cadena para concatenarlo, como veo que estás haciendo:

<s>`$resultado = '<html><h2>Productos:</h2><p>'.for`</s>

```
                                           ^ el punto es para concatenar cadenas,
                                             for no es una cadena
```

En estos casos, yo prefiero particularmente inicializar una variable e irle concatenando el contenido usando `.=` y al final hago  `echo` de esa variable.

Así el código queda más organizado y más fácil de analizar.

Por ejemplo en tu caso, algo así:

```
<?php 

    /*Inicializar variable sobre la cual se irá concatenando*/
    $resultado = '<html><h2>Productos:</h2><p>';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST["productos"]); $i++){
        $resultado.='<b>'.$_POST["productos"][$i].'</b>';
    }

    $resultado.='</p></html>';
    /*Imprimimos la variable*/
    echo $resultado;
?>
```

Quizá convenga mejorar todavía un poco el código, ya que más arriba, si son varios productos, te saldrán todos juntos.

Si quieres una separación de al menos una línea entre cada producto, puedes hacer algo así:

```
<?php 

    /*Inicializar variable sobre la cual se irá concatenando*/
    $resultado = '<h2>Productos:</h2>';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST["productos"]); $i++){
        $resultado.='<b>'.$_POST["productos"][$i].'</b><br />';
    }

    /*Imprimimos la variable*/
    echo $resultado;
?>
```

Nótese que he quitado la etiqueta `<html>`, la cual debe usarse únicamente si ese fragmento de código es todo lo que hay en tu página y no has creado ya dicha etiqueta de otro modo. En caso contrario, poner otra vez dicha etiqueta sería duplicarla.

- Para más detalles sobre la combinación de código PHP/HTML, puedes consultar [la respuesta a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92203/29967).

Comment: Amigo eres el mejor, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.. es exactamente lo que buscaba..

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres imprimir el array puede usar implode:

```
<?php
   // suponiendo estos valores para el array
   $_POST["productos"] = array('hola','mundo','con','implode');
   $resultado = '<html><h2>Productos:</h2><p><b>'.implode("<b></b>", $_POST["productos"])'</b></p></html>';
?>
```

la salida seria:

```
<html>
    <h2>Productos:</h2>
    <p>
       <b>hola</b>
       <b>mundo</b>
       <b>con</b>
       <b>implode</b>
    </p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas noches. Saca el bucle de la variable.

```
<?php 
$datos = [uno, dos, tres, cuatro]; // sustituye a $_POST["productos"]
$resultado = '<h2>Productos:</h2><p>';
for ($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++){
     $resultado .= '<b>'.$datos[$i].'</b> '; 
    } 
$resultado .= '</p>';
echo $resultado;
?>
```